# Simplest possible Angular Carousel

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make the simplest possible Angular Carousel in an effort to understand Angular better. I am aware I have asked similar angular questions and people gave me good answers that I was able to implement, but I am asking questions that will help me towards a deeper understanding of Angular2+ and Typescript so please bear with me.

So far I have:

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <img src="{{ this.showSlide(slides, i) }}" alt="slide" >
  </div>

 <button ng-click='getPrev(slides, i)'>Prev</button>

 <button ng-click='getNext(slides, i)'>Next</button>

</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-slider',
  templateUrl: './image-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-slider.component.css'],

})

export class ImageSliderComponent implements OnInit {

public slides: string [] = ['./assets/SBI_Slide_1.jpg', './assets/Eagle_Slide_2.jpg', './assets/Knot_Slide_3.jpg' ]
i: number;

showSlide(slides, i) {
    let slide = slides[i];
    return slide;
}

getPrev(slides, i) {
    i = i - 1;
    this.showSlide(slides, i)
}

getNext(slides, i) {
    i = i + 1;
    this.showSlide(slides, i)
}



  ngOnInit() {
    this.i = 0;
  }

}
```

Why does this not work? Is it because I need to update the img html element? My ng-click code doesn't seem to be doing anything!

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but could you explain further? Preferably with an example of what I should do instead?

Comment: Ahhhhh! I see - I need to use ng-if

Comment: OK I did that and it doesn't seem to be a complete solution to my problem - there must be something wrong with my methods? The picture does not update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:
I posted this answer before I saw you found the way.
I will point out the small mistakes:

ng-click is not an Angular directive, use (click) instead;

'this' keyword is not accessible from the template, but the property is, as Angular takes care of binding the template to the class.

You should always check values, before incrementing/decrementing as you may occur to indefined (i.e. i value maybe < that 0 or >  slides.length)

---

I would do it this way, but beware I didn't run:

**HTML**

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <img src="{{ getSlide() }}" alt="slide" >
  </div>

 <button (click)='getPrev()'>Prev</button>

 <button (click)='getNext()'>Next</button>

</div>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-slider',
  templateUrl: './image-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-slider.component.css'],

})

export class ImageSliderComponent  {

    slides: string [] = ['./assets/SBI_Slide_1.jpg', './assets/Eagle_Slide_2.jpg', './assets/Knot_Slide_3.jpg' ]
    i=0;

    getSlide() {
        return this.slides[this.i];
    }

    getPrev() {
        this.i = this.i===0 ? 0 : this.i - 1;
    }
//edit here    
    getNext() {
        this.i = this.i===this.slides.length ? this.i : this.i + 1;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering a bit late but I tested and here is better, clean code.  I hope it provides the help that someone is looking for.

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <img src="{{ getSlide() }}" alt="slide" />
  </div>

  <button (click)="getPrev()">Prev</button>

  <button (click)="getNext()">Next</button>
</div>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent {
  slides: string[];
  i: number;

  constructor() {
    this.i = 0;
    this.slides = [
      'https://ep01.epimg.net/elcomidista/imagenes/2022/10/31/articulo/1667206537_604382_1667230832_noticia_normal.jpg',
      'https://storage.googleapis.com/css-photos/menu-photos/1d2d5a63-1603-473b-9464-e8fa6787f40b.jpeg',
      'https://ep01.epimg.net/elcomidista/imagenes/2022/01/11/receta/1641893642_902475_1641893828_noticia_normal.jpg',
    ];
  }
  getSlide() {
    return this.slides[this.i];
  }

  getPrev() {
    this.i == 0 ? (this.i = this.slides.length - 1) : this.i--;
  }

  getNext() {
    this.i < this.slides.length - 1 ? this.i++ : (this.i = 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok with the help of Vega (see above) - I have found the answer to my question.

The thing that I now would like to understand is how to get rid of 'this' in the methods.

HTML:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <img src="{{ showSlide(slides, i) }}" alt="slide" >
  </div>

 <button (click)="getPrev(slides, i)">Prev</button>

 <button (click)="getNext(slides, i)">Next</button>

</div>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageServiceService } from '../image-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-image-slider',
  templateUrl: './image-slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image-slider.component.css'],

})

export class ImageSliderComponent implements OnInit {

public slides: string [] = ['./assets/SBI_Slide_1.jpg', './assets/Eagle_Slide_2.jpg', './assets/Knot_Slide_3.jpg' ]
i: number;

showSlide(slides, i) {
    let slide = slides[i];
    return slide;
}

getPrev(slides, i) {
    this.i = this.i - 1;
    this.showSlide(slides, i)
}

getNext(slides, i) {
    this.i = this.i + 1;
    this.showSlide(slides, i)
}



  ngOnInit() {
    this.i = 1;
  }

}
```